# iOS UITableView clear values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

In my application I am having a UITableView... in the top I am having two buttons. When I click Button 1, records from web will be fetched and displayed in the table.

When I click Button 2, different records from the web will be fetched and displayed in the table.

Both the records are different.

When I am in Button 2, and do some action in the table and reload the table, it is not showing the records that are related to Button 2, instead is showing the records related to Button 1.

This happens only at table reload.

I tried this method

```
self.allPostArray=nil;
[tView reloadData];
```

but it is not working

This is the code for loading the records from web

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

     if ([httpResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [httpResponse statusCode] < 300)
     {
         NSError *error = nil;

         NSDictionary *jsData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:data
                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                 error:&error];

         //NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", response);

         if ([jsData objectForKey:RESPONSE_KEY])
         {
             NSDictionary *dic = [jsData objectForKey:RESPONSE_KEY];
             self.allPostArray = [dic objectForKey:DATA_KEY];
         }

         if (error != nil) {
             //NSLog(@"Json serialization - %@", [error description]);
         }

         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         [tView reloadData];
     }

     if (connectionError != nil) {
         //NSLog(@"ConnectionError - %@", [connectionError description]);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Could be cache? Could be a method running every time you refresh, to pull from the landing default, eg. button one's url. Troubleshoot it by removing button 1, or NSLog in every method then between every line to figure out if its loading from that url or just using cached response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had solved this issue by using BOOL value for each button and calling the function to load the datas according to the bool value. This method is not perfect it seems. but giving the result I needed. If I click Button 1, I am using the bFollower = YES; bFollowing = NO; based on this I am loading the records from the web. By this way my problem is solved. But I feel we should not load the records from web frequently.

Comment: if(bFollower==YES){
        [self performSelector:@selector(followerCurious:) withObject:refresh afterDelay:1.0f];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(followingCurious:) withObject:refresh afterDelay:1.0f];
    }
    [tView reloadData];